# HTTP Requests on aspx page - Problem with VIEWSTATE

Tags: android, asp.net, html

My problem is that i want to create a simple application for Android. I want to go this link -> http://publico.agcp.ipleiria.pt/Paginas/AvaliacoesPublico.aspx (which is from my university where i can see the tests dates), and automatically get the html code with my tests and then parse it to a list in my android application.
Parsing and put it on a list is easy. The problem is out to post the correct information on the form. I checked with fiddler and firebug the post and responses to know what i have to send.
So i came with this code:

```
hm.put("MSO_PageHashCode", "941-263790804");
        hm.put("__SPSCEditMenu", "true");
        hm.put("MSOWebPartPage_PostbackSource", "");
        hm.put("MSOTlPn_SelectedWpId", "");
        hm.put("MSOTlPn_View", "0");
        hm.put("MSOTlPn_ShowSettings", "False");
        hm.put("MSOGallery_SelectedLibrary", "");
        hm.put("MSOGallery_FilterString", "");
        hm.put("MSOTlPn_Button", "none");
        hm.put("MSOAuthoringConsole_FormContext", "");
        hm.put("MSOAC_EditDuringWorkflow", "");
        hm.put("MSOSPWebPartManager_DisplayModeName", "Browse");
        hm.put("__EVENTTARGET", "");
        hm.put("__EVENTARGUMENT", "");
        hm.put("__SCROLLPOSITIONX", "0");
        hm.put("__SCROLLPOSITIONY", "0");
        hm.put("MSOWebPartPage_Shared", "");
        hm.put("MSOLayout_LayoutChanges", "");
        hm.put("MSOLayout_InDesignMode", "");
        hm.put("MSOSPWebPartManager_OldDisplayModeName", "Browse");
        hm.put("MSOSPWebPartManager_StartWebPartEditingName", "false");
        hm.put("__LASTFOCUS", "");
        hm.put("__REQUESTDIGEST", "0x27AFB1B27830DB0B954C6852D518E1F7D3A125761B5C738CD230D1A51E007B8EAF3D77D049713E4E45460482B1E8AF3398225C845AEBB2F16279B3526DCC4A6F,04 
    Sep 2011 03:05:11 -0000");
        hm.put("__VIEWSTATE", this.getInitialViewstate());
        hm.put("__EVENTVALIDATION", "");
        hm.put("ctl00_ctl12$ctl00", "http://spserver:7250");
        hm.put("ctl00_PlaceHolderAGCPUO_ddlUO", "2");
        hm.put("ctl00_PlaceHolderAGCPUO_ddlAnosLectivos", "34");
        hm.put("ctl00_PlaceHolderAGCPUO_ddlSemestres", "S2");
        hm.put("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_txtCodCurso", "");
        hm.put("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ddlCursos", "9099");
        hm.put("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ddlAnosCurr", "3");
        hm.put("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ddlPlanos", "1");
        hm.put("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ddlRamos", "0");
        hm.put("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ddlTurmas", "TESTEG1D");
        hm.put("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ddlDisciplina", "0");
        hm.put("__spDummyText1", "__spDummyText1");
        hm.put("__spDummyText2", "__spDummyText2");

    try {
                doSubmit(sUrl, hm);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            //function

        public void doSubmit(String url, HashMap<String, String> data) throws Exception {
        URL siteUrl = new URL("http://publico.agcp.ipleiria.pt/Paginas/AvaliacoesPublico.aspx");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) siteUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);

        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

        Set keys = data.keySet();
        Iterator keyIter = keys.iterator();
        String content = "";
        for(int i=0; keyIter.hasNext(); i++) {
            Object key = keyIter.next();
            if(i!=0) {
                content += "&";
            }
            content += key + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(data.get(key), "UTF-8");
        }
        System.out.println(content);
        out.writeBytes(content);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        while((line=in.readLine())!=null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        in.close();
    }
```

So far so good. The problem is the VIEWSTATE. Which ever value i use on the other parameters of the form i cannot get what i want. But if i put the VIEWSTATE value obtained with fidler when passing all those comboboxes to get to my course, i get the html that i want.

How can i solve this? I cannot hardcode the viewstate value, cause i want to get dynamically the course test dates. 
Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve this is to issue a GET request prior to the post. You can then extract the VIEWSTATE from the response and use that value in your POST request.

Comment: Didn't work :( i got the html like i was visiting the site for the first time.

Comment: Petter, is there any other way? Right now, I'm making an additional HttpGet for the VIEWSTATE making the online update slower.

Comment: The problem with that is that you may need to provide the EventTarget and EventArgument variables. These are set via javascript during the submission in the browser. The server then examines them to determine what action was taken on the client in order to process the correct event. If no event is detected it will not register a post back and therefore serve the page like a GET again.